# can't find variable: $j

Tags: jquery, variables

Why do I encounter this

```
can't find variable: $j
```

when i use this method

```javascript
function myMethod(htmlObject)
{
    var buttonTags = $j("button",htmlObject);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My psychic powers tell me you're trying to use jQuery. In which case the name of the function is just `$` (or `jQuery`) not `$j`.

Comment: erm sorry i forgot to mention in a hurry, yes i'm using JQuery. I've use $j and it works in other pages.
what the difference btw $j and $

Comment: `$j` is non-standard name. It's sometimes used when you're using jQuery with another library that also overrides the '$' variable. Sometimes you'll see `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` at the top of the page which is why it may have worked for you on other pages.

Comment: oh yes i think its that cause.
Anyways i've used another method without using jquery.
thank you for the clarification anyway!have a great day ahead!

Comment: @orangebrainer: if this answers your question, it would be much appreciated if you click the outline of a "tick" next to this answer to mark it as "correct".